# Monopoly: If I had all properties of a colour but sold one of them, will I retain houses on the other properties of that colour?

Tags: monopoly

Let's say I have every property of a colour, and sold one of them to another player. Since I won't have all properties of that colour anymore, will I lose all the houses I built on the other properties of that colour (which I haven't sold). Or will I still retain them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This cannot happen as stated. You have to sell off improvements before you can sell the property. From the [rules of Monopoly](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/00009.pdf):

> Selling Property
>
> > Unimproved properties, railroads and utilities may be sold to any player as a private transaction for any amount the owner can get. However, properties can not be sold to another player if buildings are standing on any properties of that color-group. The buildings must be sold back to the Bank before the owner can sell any property of that color-group.

Comment: The complementary rule is that you must have a complete set to develop any property in that set.